# Django 1.7 tutorial: Use generic views

Tags: django, generics, jython

I need to use Jython instead of Python, I found that jython2.7b2 works with DJango 1.7. So, I am stuck using the beta version.  I am trying to follow the current Django tutorial and I have ran into a problem.  I am not sure if I am using generic views properly.  When I try to change the urls.py (polls) file. I see that pydev complains that views.IndexView, views.DetailView, and ResultsView don't exist.  Am I doing something wrong?  Or did they change the way generics work in version 1.7?

My System:

- Windows 7
- jython2.7b2
- Django-1.7c3
- postgresql-9.3.5-1-windows-x64
- postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar

Here is the url for the tutorial, go to the section "Use generic views: Less code is better"
[Django tutorial part 04](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/#use-generic-views-less-code-is-better)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Once you have changed your urls.py, you need to define the new views.

This is covered in the next section of the tutorials, [*Amend views*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial04/#amend-views).